# Scope composables to a parent composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm making an implementation of `PreferencesScreen` in `Compose` and I've made all the components like `PreferencesSwitch`, `CheckBox`, etc.
Now I'm wondering if there is any way to make it so all the components can only be used inside the scope of the `PreferencesScreen` function and cannot be used outside of it.
Like for example, in `LazyColumn`, `items` can only be used inside `LazyColumnScope`. I looked at the implementation of it but it used the annotation `@LazyScopeMarker` so I'm assuming there's different markers for different scopes?

**Expected Behaviour:**

```
PreferencesScreen{
    PreferencesCheckBox(...){ ... }
}
```

is possible but,

```
PreferencesCheckBox(...){ ... }
```

alone is not possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can declare some scope same like `LazyColumn` does:

```
interface PreferencesScreenScope {
    @Composable
    fun PreferencesCheckBox()
}

private class PreferencesScreenScopeImpl: PreferencesScreenScope {
    @Composable
    override fun PreferencesCheckBox() {

    }
}
```

`interface`/`class ...Impl` is used here to make sure that no other screen can reuse `PreferencesScreenScopeImpl`, also it adds testing possibility.

Use it in `PreferencesScreen`:

```
@Composable
fun PreferencesScreen(content: @Composable PreferencesScreenScope.() -> Unit ) {
    PreferencesScreenScopeImpl().content()
}
```

Use `PreferencesScreen` like this:

```
PreferencesScreen {
    PreferencesCheckBox()
}
```

Comment: This implementation doesn't restrict which composables are called inside your `content` lambda.

Comment: @AouledIssa I'm not sure it's possible restrict, do you know any system view examples that does it?

Comment: One of the possible ways I see is to use either wrapper classes around your composables or to use custom scopes with functions that call your composables.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add functions to `LazyListScope`, but only make them available under `Preferences`. The simplest way I found is to use an interface as a flag and delegate the implementation of `LazyListScope`.

```
@Composable
fun Preferences(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> = LocalContext.current.settingsDataStore,
    content: PreferencesScope.() -> Unit
) {
    PreferencesProvider(dataStore = dataStore) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = modifier) {
            content(PreferencesScopeImpl(this))
        }
    }
}

interface PreferencesScope : LazyListScope
class PreferencesScopeImpl(lazyListScope: LazyListScope): PreferencesScope, LazyListScope by lazyListScope
```

Now I can write extension functions using `PreferencesScope`.

```
fun PreferencesScope.preferenceItem(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    title: String,
    description: String? = null,
    onClick: () -> Unit = {}
) {
    item {
        PreferenceItem(
            modifier = modifier,
            title = title,
            description = description,
            onClick = onClick
        )
    }
}
```